# Why do not people use subject and am,is,are in social media?

Tags: american-english, british-english

I am a beginner learner and i see posts in social media like:
telling my friend where is my phone.

İn this sentence i am thinking like it is present continuous tense and we should add "I am" at the beginning.
Also if this is normal, can we talk like that in daily life?

Comment: It's hard to type on a phone.

Comment: Conversational deletion. See the linked question for details.

Comment: i found what I needed now. Thank you.